# App crashing while retrieving data from mysql

Tags: android, mysql, crash

Hi guys im new to android studio so im still learning. But today I encountered something which I cant resolve. Everytime I execute inside Asyntax an sql query like `"select * from databasename"` and do something like `while(rs.next)` my app keeps on crashing. I made sure I made the connection from the database.

*ps. i even tried the strictmode to query in the main but same result keeps crashing*

I have tried every tutorial online to the point I copied every single thing and downloaded their source code but I ended up with the same result.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnShow = findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetData retrieveData = new GetData();
            retrieveData.execute();
        }
    });
}
 private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    String msg="";
    final TextView textShow = findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    final TextView textShow1 = findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + ConnectURL.DATABASE_URL + "/" + ConnectURL.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        String Xmsg="Connecting to database...";
        textShow.setText(Xmsg);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, ConnectURL.USERNAME, ConnectURL.PASSWORD);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "Select * from poultryinfo";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData rmrs = rs.getMetaData();

            msg="Connection completed";

           while(rs.next()) {
               msg += rmrs.getColumnName(2) + ":" + rs.getString("valName") + "\n";
            }

            textShow1.setText(msg);

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException connError){
            msg="An exception was thrown JDBC"+ connError.toString();
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "A class not found exception" + e.toString();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = e.toString();
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = e.toString();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void  onPostExecute(String msg){
        textShow.setText(this.msg);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my xml file I dont think theres anything wrong with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnShow" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtView1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
    android:text="@string/show"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and these are the logcat im getting

```
10-08 18:33:58.620 25502-25502/? E/Zygote: v2
10-08 18:33:58.620 25502-25502/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-08 18:34:00.250 25502-25502/com.example.jade.connectionpractice E/Qmage: 
isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
10-08 18:34:02.830 25502-25813/com.example.jade.connectionpractice 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.jade.connectionpractice, PID: 25502
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing 
 doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8355)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1327)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20170)
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8425)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5011)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4836)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4811)
    at com.example.jade.connectionpractice.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
    at com.example.jade.connectionpractice.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message in the stack trace has explained the issue to you:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

This tells me you are trying to manipulate a view (e.g. update text) from non UI thread. The cuplrit:

```
textShow1.setText(msg);
```

**Solution:**

after `doInBackground`, `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread, so move `textShow1.setText(msg);` there and make `doInBackground` return `msg` instead of `null`

Comment: Welp! Looks like I have to learn to read! Sorry man I just didnt see that on the logcat and didnt know what it meant xD! Thank you it worked tho! :)

Comment: @JBie no problem, always look through your stack traces for "caused by". Also, because you're new here, don't forget you can click the tick and arrows on the left of an answer to mark your problem as resolved / thank the answerer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do UI oprerations inside `doInBackground`, you can use `runOnUiThread` as below

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //do your UI operations here
            textShow1.setText(msg);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but doing this from an AsyncTask would be a complete hack, defeating the purpose of an *async* task